# Value Error when trying to append dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

ValueError: Length of passed values is 4, index implies 3

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import pandas as pd

url_wiki = 'https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_dos_distritos_de_S%C3%A3o_Paulo_por_popula%C3%A7%C3%A3o'

response = requests.get(url_wiki)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

table = soup.find('table', {'class':'wikitable sortable'}).tbody

rows = table.find_all('tr')

columns= [v.text.replace('\n', '') for v in rows[0].find_all('th')]

print(columns)

'#columns has 3 elements!!'

df=pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

#now have to populate the table
for i in range (1,len(rows)): #find skipping the first row, search in all rows
    tds=rows[i].find_all('td')
    #inspect ...rowspan 2 td tags, otherwise 3 td tags
    if len(tds) == 2:
        values = [tds[0].text.replace('\n', ''), tds[1].text.replace('\n', ''), tds[2].text.replace('\n', '')]
    else:
        values=[td.text.replace('\n', '') for td in tds]
    #print(values)
```

everything looks fine up to now

when I run the line below, I get the error. Check the comment above, index has 3 elements

also by running #print(values) above it is clear the table has 3 column.

What am I missing here

```
    df=df.append(pd.Series(values, index=columns), ignore_index=True)
    df
```

### Traceback

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-210-2fa24a66fa93> in <module>
----> 1 df=df.append(pd.Series(values, index=columns), ignore_index=True)

e:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __init__(self, data, index, dtype, name, copy, fastpath)
    319                 try:
    320                     if len(index) != len(data):
--> 321                         raise ValueError(
    322                             f"Length of passed values is {len(data)}, "
    323                             f"index implies {len(index)}."

ValueError: Length of passed values is 4, index implies 3.
```

Comment: What you're missing is (1) the full error message (include the trace-back); (2) minimal code to reproduce the problem; (3) tracing the problem values at the point of error.

Comment: The last row of the table has 4 columns. You can adjust your code to ignore the last column, or you could edit the source directly (not usually an option, but it is wikipedia...).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Prune and @goalie1998.
Realized the problem and solved it. There is a 'bug' in the original table, a hidden column in the last empty row.
Solved it by substracting 1 here:

for i in range (1,len(rows)-1): #find skipping the first row, search in all rows

Cheers